# Not able to resolve dependencies of jar file

Tags: java

I have a web application that was deployed in tomcat. As part of third party library i am getting standalone jar file from my vendors. This jar file is set of few folders as well as class files and lib folder. this lib folder contains libraries which is required by the classes. Now i want to call the method of class (belongs to stand alone jar) in my web application and want to execute that method.when i tried it was throwing error not able to resolve dependency of jar files which is getting used by claases of standalone jar. Can somebody give me some thoughts on this.

Comment: Did you put the jar in WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: I am not sure about

Whether You have added `jar` files Properly or not.